# Postgres won't start after deleting pg_xlog files

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Using Debian Wheezy, Postgresql 9.3

My database went down because the partition where it keeps the WAL files got full.
So, I deleted everything inside `./pg_xlog/` , because I didn't know what they were (yea, incredibly stupid of me). Now the Postgres service won't start, though the problem, according to syslog:

```
00000: could not open tablespace directory "pg_tblspc/16386/PG_9.3_201306121": File or directory not found
LOCAL:  RelationCacheInitFileRemoveInDir, relcache.c:4895
00000: Primary checkpoint record is invalid
LOCAL:  ReadCheckpointRecord, xlog.c:6543
00000: Secondary checkpoint record is invalid
LOCAL:  ReadCheckpointRecord, xlog.c:6547
PANIC: XX000: could not locate a valid checkpoint record
LOCAL:  StartupXLOG, xlog.c:5228
```

I'm not entirely sure whether the problem is that it can't find the proper pg_tblspc or the total lack of checkpoint WAL files. The actual path to where the databases are stored is `/dados/PG_9.3_201306121`. What can I do to make the service start again?

**EDIT1:**
Okay, I've managed to get the thing back online. Some databases got corrupt. I've managed to `DROPDB` two of them (couldn't even connect to them without them forcing a service restart). I tried doing it to another one that got corrupt, but the error was related to xlog again. I've tried doing a clean restore over it, but the restore was incomplete. Then, I've created a new database and tried to restore an older backup of this database. It also came incomplete.

Now I can't drop any databases, nor create new ones, I always get a `xlog flush request not satisfied` error. I've tried running `pg_resetxlog`, but it didn't seem to do anything. Another thing the error shows is `cannot write to block 1 of pg_tblspc/16385/PG_9.3_201306121/36596452/11773`, `write error may be permanent`.

**EDIT2:** Part of the problem above was with that 11773 file. I've renamed it to 11773.corrupt and now the database allows me to create and drop again.

Comment: Nonono, don't keep using it! Back it up, shut it down, rename the old data directory, `initdb` a new one (or use your package's wrapper, however you first set it up) and then restore your dumps to the new PostgreSQL instance.

Answer (score 7):

> Postgres won't start after deleting pg_xlog files

Um, yeah. Don't do that.

> What can I do to make the service start again?

Well, you've corrupted your database. Restore from backups. You have backups, right? Preferably a handy PITR archive like from PgBarman where you can restore up to 5 mins ago. No?

OK, first, archive the damaged copy. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption

Now. If you're lucky, `pg_resetxlog` will get you up and running enough to successfully do a `pg_dump` of the database, so you can then move the old damaged install's datadir aside, `initdb` a new one, and restore the database to it.

If you're unlucky `pg_dump` won't succeed, or you'll get restore failures due to things like duplicate primary keys. In the latter case might have to repair the dump by hand. If `pg_dump` fails, appropriate action will depend on why it fails.

So yeah. Don't delete `pg_xlog`.

There are discussions within the PostgreSQL community about renaming `pg_xlog` to something that makes it more obvious that it's an important component of the database, and hopefully it'll get done in the 9.7 release.

Comment: Okay, I've got the backups, but now some of the databases are corrupt. Well, this wouldn't be a problem, but now I can't DROP or CREATE databases, I always get a "xlog flush request not satisfied" error

Comment: You'll have to initdb,